# $on not getting triggered while using $broadcast

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular app, there are 2 controllers.

**file1.js**

```
angular.module(appName).controller('controller1', function($scope,$state){

   $scope.goTofile2 = function(){
      $state.go('file2');
   }

   $scope.$on('broadcastFromFile2', function () {
    // something to do
});

});
```

**file2.js**

```
angular.module(appName).controller('controller1', function($rootScope,$state){

   $scope.triggerBroadcast = function(){
      $rootScope.$broadcast('broadcastFromFile2');
   }

});
```

**Scenario**

From file 1 , the app will navigate to file 2 when `$scope.goTofile2()` is triggered. Once it reaches file 2, on click of a button `$scope.triggerBroadcast()` will be triggered and it will in turn trigger a broadcast `broadcastFromFile2` and some code is written in `$scope.$on('broadcastFromFile2', function () { })` which is in file1

**Issue**

On clicking the button in file 2, the `$broadcast` is getting triggered but the corresponding $on is not working. What is the possible reason. is it because these are not parent -> child controllers ?

Comment: When you leave a state the controller(s) for that state are destroyed as are their event listeners

Comment: @charlietfl What is the solution for this ?

Comment: For what exactly? Why are you needing a non existent controller to receive events? Need to explain your higher level problem in more detail

Comment: @charlietfl I have some  logic done in controller 1. Need to trigger those from controller 2.

Comment: Logic to do what? You just left that view and there is no need for that controller. If it is to store data or  share business logic then use a  service

Comment: Controller is to control view, if you do not have view you do not need controller. You probably want to put your $on callback to service/factory.

Answer (score 0):

The `$on` logic is not getting triggered because the scope of the 'controller1' (file1) finished when you navigated to 'controller2' (file2). If you want to implement this `$broadcast` and `$on` logic, put it in a service.

Services are singleton and they will maintain a single instance across your controllers.

So in `controller1` you can have a statement like:

```
myService.setEventListener()
```

and in `controller2` you can have a statement like:

```
myService.broadcastEvent()
```

Create a new service like this:

```
app.factory('myService', function($rootScope){
  function setEventListener() {
    $rootScope.$on('broadcastFromFile2', function () {
      // Handle event here
    })
  }

  function broadcastEvent() {
    // Broadcast event here
    $rootScope.$broadcastEvent('broadcastFromFile2')
  }
  return {
    setEventListener: setEventListener,
    broadcastEvent: broadcastEvent

  }
})
```